# Activity Does not Work for resultCode 4 5 6

Tags: android, camera

My Activity for selecting images from gallery and showing on imagebuttons does not work for request code 3 4 5 here is my activity result code

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {


    //getting uri from intent extras


        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

        cursor.close();
        btmp[requestCode]= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);


    switch (requestCode){
        case 0:
            img1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            bt1=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            break;
        case 1:
            img2.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            bt2=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            break;
        case 2:
            img3.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            bt3=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            break;
        case 3:
            bt4=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            img4.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            break;
        case 4:
            bt5=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            img5.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            break;
        case 5:
            bt6=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            img6.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            break;
    }


}
```

Comment: "Does not work" is a bad error description. What exactly does not work? Is the `onActivityResult()` method not called?

Comment: well it return to home page or some time the images 1 2 3 disapears unable to figure out the error

Comment: Well you decode the bitmap thrice instead of using btmp[requestCode] as a parameter for the setImageBitmap() and for the bt1 to bt6. Beside that I don't see an issue in your code. Have you tried to debug?

Comment: how are you calling startActivityForResult?